# Ancestry with more than object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

I need to dispaly a list of activities and each activity can have services and I have to use ancestry gem for that.

This is how I proceed:

```
module ActivitiesHelper
 def nested_activities(activities)  
    activities.each do |act|
        render(act) + content_tag(:ul, nested_activities(act.services) ) 
    end.join.html_safe  
 end  
end
```

**edit**
I got this error

```
Missing partial activities/_activity with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

Comment: ha? So what. What's the question?

Comment: the question that this does not work

Comment: When you call `render(act)` render searches for a partial named '_activity.html.erb' inside `activities` views folder

Comment: if I got this error what does this means 'stack level too deep' ?